# file upload work localhost but doesn't work on server in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, server, temporary-asp.net-files

I can add localde when uploading files. But when I try it on the server, I get a 404 not found error.
Normally, when redirecting url in my project, I do it as "url:" @ ViewBag.UrlPath / api / AddDocument / GetTechDocCode / ",".

While uploading the file, I used "url:" / DokumanEstablishment / Test ",".

Am I having an error while redirecting, what could be caused by this problem?

Comment: Do you have write permission on the server folder?

Comment: When I search, when there is an authorization error, in the console gives permission error. I guess my fault is with the redirect settings. I did not go the way normally used in the project. If I write the url part correctly, it looks like it won't be a problem, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: The paths are not clear in your question, are using any js library or ajax upload? it would be more helpful if you provide the upload code block on both, front end and backend.